# Node server started but i can't access it trough my IP on centos

Tags: node.js, express, centos, centos6, forever

I've started node server with forever

`forever start server.js`

I verified it with `forever list` and also with opened the 3000 port in iptables and made sure that the port is open and listening with `nmap`. So node is runing and the app responding but i can't access it trough my ip

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000

I'm using VPS - any idea where can i start looking for a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server is doing a `.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');` you might try changing it to `.listen(3000);` or `.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');`